# Writing a love calculator

Tags: r

Here is the code for my Love Compatibility Calculator

```
love.compatability.2 = function(x, y) {
    a = nchar(x)/1.2
    b = nchar(y)/1.2
    c = a*b
    d = ifelse(c>100, c/2, c)
    classify(d)
}

classify = function(x) {
    if(0 <= x & x <= 9.99){'0-9%'}
    else if(10 <= x & x <= 19.99){'10-19%'}
    else if(20 <= x & x <= 29.99){'20-29%'}
    else if(30 <= x & x <= 39.99){'30-39%'}
    else if(40 <= x & x <= 49.99){'40-49%'}
    else if(50 <= x & x <= 59.99){'50-59%'}
    else if(60 <= x & x <= 69.99){'60-69%'}
    else if(70 <= x & x <= 79.99){'70-79%'}
    else if(80 <= x & x <= 89.99){'80-89%'}
    else if(90 <= x & x <= 100){'90-100%'}
    else{'It cannot be known'}
}
```

The input is two full names in inverted commas. e.g. "John Salter","Your Mother"

To improve it, I'd like to find a way of incorporating the type of letters in each name into the love%

Can anyone suggest a way this could be done? Do you have any ideas for funny ways of classifying the result?

Comment: Maybe try `ifelse(c > 100, 100 - c, c)`? But I'm worried you're confused about `ifelse`. It is something rather different than your standard `if-else` conditional logic tool found in most languages.

Comment: aside: one reason why you should start using `<-` instead of `=` because this would have worked `ifelse(101 > 100, d <- 100 - 5, 5); d`

Comment: Maybe it just the poor formatting in your question, but it looks like you have a lot of syntax errors. For example, `Error in assess.compatibility("string 1", "string two") : 
  object 'a' not found`

Comment: You are very unlikely to achieve criterion #2. Also, you have no criterion #5, despite talking about it.

Comment: I'd like to use this when you're finished :)

Comment: How about `sqrt(a*b)/max(a,b)`?

Comment: Please see edited post!

Comment: You might also be interested in the `cut` function - it could clean up your `classify` code.

Comment: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=caRlSclp @RichardScriven found you a great match

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Java code : **love compatibility calculator    .......Happy dating.**

Written by: Dancan Angwenyi

University of Cape Town

Happy coding*/

import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;


public class problemd


{

public static void main(final String[] args){ 


final  String alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";



Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while(input.hasNextLine()){

     String v = input.nextLine();
     String two = input.nextLine();
     String data = v.toLowerCase();
     char data1[]= data.toCharArray();
     int  num_1=0 ;
     int num_2=0 ;
     for (char s : data1){
       int k = alphabet.indexOf(s)+1;
       num_1+=k;
       //System.out.println(k);
     }
     String data2= two.toLowerCase();
     char dat2[] = data2.toCharArray();
     for (char t : dat2){
       double p = alphabet.indexOf(t)+1;
       num_2+=p;
       //System.out.println(p);

     }
     double sum_1 = 0.00;
     double sum_2 = 0.00;

     while (num_1 != 0) {
        double rem_1;
        rem_1 = num_1 % 10;
        sum_1 = sum_1+ rem_1;
        num_1 = num_1 / 10;
        if (num_1==0 && sum_1>9){
            num_1=(int)sum_1;
            sum_1=0.0;}
     }
     while (num_2 != 0) {
       double rem_2;
        rem_2 = num_2 % 10;
        sum_2 = sum_2 + rem_2;
        num_2 = num_2 / 10;
        if (num_2==0 && sum_2>9){
            num_2=(int)sum_2;
            sum_2=0.0;}


    } 
    //System.out.println(sum_1);
   // System.out.println(sum_2);

    if(sum_1 > sum_2){
     double percent = ( sum_2/sum_1)*100;
     System.out.printf("%.2f %%\n",percent);
    }
    else if(sum_1 == sum_2){
     double percent = ( sum_2/sum_1)*100;
     System.out.printf("%.2f %%\n",percent);
    }
    else if(sum_1 < sum_2){
     double percent = ( sum_1/sum_2)*100;
     System.out.printf("%.2f %%\n",percent);
    }

  }

}

}
```